# Using exception for invalid entry

Tags: java, if-statement, exception

I am trying to use exceptions in my assignment to catch an error when a user input invalid entry.

I tried using the if else statement to catch but whenever running the program it will skipped pass my exception even when I input invalid entry. Do any of you have any idea where I am wrong in the code?

PS: please have mercy and go easy on me as I am still learning

```
private static void initArray() throws Exception {
    while(true) {
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        if(!name.contains(" ")){
            System.out.println("Please enter the coin:");
            try {
                int coinValue = scanner.nextInt();
                    if(coinValue>= 5){
                        if(coinValue % 5 != 1){
                            Change c = new Change(name, coinValue);
                            addChangeObject(c);
                        }else {
                            throw new Exception("invalid value);                            
                            }

                        }
            }catch (Exception e){
                c.setMessage(e.setMessage);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing an exception at the appropriate condition, but then immediately catching that exception. After the `catch` block the execution continues to prompt for another user.

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. You can have a `continue` statement in the `catch` block to continue with the next execution of the containing `while(true)` loop, but that would require the user to re-enter a name before entering another coin value.
2. The other option is to have another `while(true)` loop wrapping the `try-catch` block prompting for coins and a `break` statement if the conditions are met. Something like this:

```java
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the coin value for the person (multiple of 5):");
    int coinValue = scanner.nextInt();
    try {
        if (coinValue >= 5 && coinValue <= 1000 && coinValue % 5 == 0) {
            Change c = new Change(name, coinValue);
            addChangeObject(c);
            break;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Value not within 5 to 1000 and not mutliples of 5");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catch logic asking the user to re-enter a coin value
        System.out.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```